# Apt-get fails Errors were encountered while processing openafs-client

Tags: apt

This fails for any `sudo apt-get install <package>`
The command `sudo /etc/openafs/openafs-client start`
failed because the control process exited with error code:

```
openafs-client precheck[31033] ...precheck:24 /etc/openafs.afs.conc: -debug not found
afsd[31041]: adsd: some file missing or bad in /etc/openafs
systems[1]: openafs-client.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1
rmmod[31042]: kmod version 24
rmmod[31042]: -XZ -ZLIB -EXPERIMENTAL
systems[1]: openafs-client.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

ls /etc/openaf shoes
afs.conf
afs.conf.client
afs.server.prefs
cacheinfo
CellServDB
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this Ubuntu machine for a long time. I believe that the openafs failure had to do with a repository that had been removed.
I used "sudo apt full-update" which resolved the problem.